# Addin tabs, panels and few more elements to extjs.window

Tags: extjs

I am trying to open a extjs window in which I want to use panels on one side and tabs on another. on tabpanel I want to use formpanel, combobox and gridview on different panels. I know it is too much to ask. I looked online and found many examples how to do all these individually but what is the best way to combine these functions?

Here is the link where I found most of the examples:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130113094550/http://extjs.wima.co.uk/

Answer (score 1):

> Panels on one side and Tabs on another

If you mean, a `panel` on the left and `Tabs` on the right, then use the `border` layout. One the left set a `panel` as an item of the `west` region. On the right hand side, put a `Tabpanel`. Each tab of the panel can contain each of the items that you mentioned.

```
Ext.Window({
 layout : 'border'
 items : [{
  xtype : 'panel'
  region : 'west'
  items : [{
   //.. Any items you need
  }]
 },{
  xtype : 'tabpanel',
  region : 'center' // DONOT FORGET!
  items : [{
   xtype : 'form',
   itmes : [{
    //..Any form items that you need, including comboboxes
   }]
   },
   {
    xtype : 'grid',
    // other configs of grid
   },
   {
   // Any other components you desire
   }
  ]
 }]
});
```

Add whatever other configuration options that you need. [Ext JS api](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/) is pretty well written.